# Use Local Storage in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am developing app using angular js. I have problem while using localstorage. My code looks:

```
var id = response.data[0].id;
var email = response.data[0].email;
localStorage.setItem('userId', id);
localStorage.setItem('email', email);
```

I have set two values in localstorage.I am getting these values in run function

```
run(function($rootScope,$location) {           
    var userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        alert(userId);
    });         
})
```

My Problem is userId shows null first time when I refresh page then it alert me values. How can i get value without refresh page.

Comment: get your user id from storage in locationchangestart method

Comment: When I refresh page then it shows me value.I want value first time without refresh page

Comment: if it has never been set the value in alert will never be updated. It will always be value it was when page loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the Solution .Problem is I get localstorage outside the 
$locationChangeStart' method.

Here is the correct way:

```
run(function($rootScope,$location) {           
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
       var userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
        alert(userId);
    });         
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but i found this example for Local Storage. You can open two pages, and both wil update depending on the other one. 
[Local Storage Example](http://www.ellipsetours.com/Demos/storage/)
You will find a link to the sourcecode in the bottom right corner.

Answer (score -2):

```
$window.localStoage.setItem("key","Value");
```

Comment: A snippet of code with no explanation is not a proper answer

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.